# How to access the feed of my wordpress guest blog?

Tags: wordpress, parsing, rss, feed

How can I access a feed list (RSS, Atom) of my guest blog on wordpress, I don't want the content of the blog (posts) but only the list (title, autor, description)

Is it possible? if yes, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your guest blog setup. To access the RSS feed of your site you need to append /feed to your URL:

```
http://yourdomain.com/feed
```

To access the feed of a certain category (if you happen to have your guest bloggers only post to a specific category:

```
http://yourdomain.com/category/<<categoryname>>/feed
```

Or on a per-Tag-basis:

```
http://yourdomain.com/tags/<<tagname>>/feed
```

That's basically it ...

Answer (score 1):

You can load feed details using following code,

```
            SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(XmlReader.Create("http://en.blog.wordpress.com/feed/"));
            IEnumerable<SyndicationItem> syndicationItems = feed.Items;
            int counter = 0;
            int maxItems = 10;
            foreach (SyndicationItem syndicationItem in syndicationItems)
            {
                if (counter >= maxItems)
                {
                    break;
                }
                counter += 1;
                Response.Write("<h4><strong>" + syndicationItem.Title.Text + "</strong></h4>");
                Response.Write("<p class='small'>Posted on " + syndicationItem.PublishDate.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy") + "</p>");
            }
```